# How are media queries different from the use of "%"?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

I know that media queries are used to create responsive layouts.

However they seem redundant; can't we achieve all we need using `%`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining layout using `%` help create a fluid layout, **NOT RESPONSIVE** layouts.

Media queries help you to define different style sets for different screen sizes.

Also with Media Queries, you don't have to be limited to *just heights and weights*, you can control more than *sizes*.

Example below creates different background for different screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
   body { 
      background: red;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 780px) {
   body { 
      background: blue;
   }
}
```

**Can `%` do that?**
No

Answer (score 3):

Percentage-based layouts are fluid-- the widths of their components can change as the viewport size changes. That does not make them responsive, however.

Responsive layouts have different CSS applied at different viewport sizes. For example, two blocks that each have 50% width and float next to each other when the viewport is large might change to have 100% width and stack on top of each other when the viewport is small.